# Why am I getting an "index too large" exception, here?

Tags: list, exception, haskell, indexing

I've tried to write a function which returns a repeated element

```
findMul :: [String] -> String
findMul [] = []
findMul s
    |ss!!0 == ss!!1 = ss!!0
    |otherwise    = findMul (tail s)
    where
    ss = sort s

sort :: [String] -> [String]
sort [] = []
sort (x:ys) = (sort ls) ++ [x] ++ (sort gs)

    where       
    ls = [y | y<-ys, y<=x]
    gs = [y | y<-ys, y>x ]
```

This seems to work when tested with the input

```
findMul ["d","c","b","a","a"]
```

which correctly returns

```
"a"
```

but when I test it with a slightly different input

```
findMul ["d","c","b","b","a"]
```

which returns the error

```
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

Could anyone possibly explain what the error means? And possibly why it occurs?

Comment: The second pattern (`findMul s`) is used in case list `s` has one or more elements; if it has only one element, you run into trouble  when you try to access the *second* (non-existent!) element of a sorted version of that list (`ss!!1`)...

Comment: By the way, this task can be easily achieved by: `[head i | i <- Data.List.group l, length i > 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort` function is fine; the problem lies in the definition of your `findMul` function. Note that the second pattern,

```
findMul s
```

is used in case list `s` is nonempty. In particular, it's used in case `s` be a singleton list (a list composed of only one element).

Moreover, lists `s` and `ss` always have the same length; therefore, if `s` only has one element, `ss` also has only one element.

However, in `ss!!1`, you're trying to access the *second* element of `ss`, which *doesn't* exist if `s` is a singleton list. You're essentially trying to access an element beyond the actual length (i.e. 1) of list `ss`! That's why Haskell is yelling at you:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matching for `findMul` can take a single element list

```
findMul ["b"]
```

when this happens, the `ss` list is also of length 1, but you are using the second element in it in the guard `ss!!1`.

This is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Using `!` for list access is often not the best idea. Use pattern matching, and things become clearer.

```
findMul (x:y:rest) = if x == y then y else findMul (y:rest)  
findMul [x] = x  -- the branch you originally missed 
findMul [] = undefined -- or what you'd prefer
```

It also becomes obvious that you find the first repetition only. Consider going full RLE :)

Comment: Run-Length Encoding. It's basically finding and counting _all_ repeating character subsequences in a string.